# Selenium Webdriver Java validate name field

Tags: java, selenium, character

I am not very experienced with Selenium. I thought to test my knowledge by doing the following, validate that a name field in a form has no special character. I was not able to do so. 1st I tried to put the characters in an array and read from the array but I kept on getting Alert failure message. Then I thought of the following way and always getting output "valid".

import junit.framework.Assert;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class NameField {
    public static FirefoxDriver fx= new FirefoxDriver();
    public static String doCheck()
    {




        fx.get("http://www.gogamers.com/#!blank/gs4id");
        String regex = "^[A-Z0-9+$";

        String str=fx.findElement(By.id("comp-iikjotq8nameField")).getText();
        fx.findElement(By.id("comp-iikjotq8nameField")).sendKeys("@john");



        if (str.matches("[" + regex + "]+")){
            System.out.println("Invalid character in Name field");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("valid");
        }
        return str;
```

What I have in mind is if you give a name using sendkey(eg: John#, @john) you will get invalid message. Another thing I was thinking should I use assertion? Please suggest a best way a small sample code would be helpful.

---

The new code that I have tried today which is still giving me Valid, when I am expecting invalid. Can someone kindly take a look please? I tried both matches and find

public class YahooMail {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    FirefoxDriver fx= new FirefoxDriver();
    fx.get("https://login.yahoo.com/account/create?");

    String title=fx.getTitle();
    Assert.assertTrue(title.contains("Yahoo"));
    //First I send a text, then I get the text
    fx.findElement(By.id("usernamereg-firstName")).sendKeys("$John");

    fx.findElement(By.id("usernamereg-firstName")).getText();

    //This is the String I want to find
    String firstName="John";

    //If there are these symbols associated with the name-show invalid
    String patternString = ".*$%^#:.*";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(firstName);
    if(matcher.find()){

        System.out.println("Invalid Name" );
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Valid Name");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your regular expression to match any *non-alphanumeric characters* and use `Pattern` and `Matcher` instead:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\W");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Invalid character in Name field");
}
else {
    System.out.println("valid");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I did to validate a name field I used same regular expression as was used by our developers in website.  Name field in my case is only accepting alphanumeric characters.  First of all I created a java functions to randomly generate alphanumeric with special characters as below and then I am comparing this auto generated input with actual regular expressions.  As special characters are not allowed in my case, if statement will return false and else block will be executed showing that special characters are not allowed.

```
//can also be used for complex passwords
public String randomSpecial(int count)
{
    String characters = "~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\\|;:\'\",<.>/?ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    String generatedString = RandomStringUtils.random(count, characters);
    return generatedString;
}



public void TC_05_regExpression_Invalid()
    {
        String regex = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]*$/";

    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("firstName"));

        element.sendKeys(randomSpecial(10));
        String fieldText = element.getAttribute("value");

        if(fieldText.matches("["+ regex + "]+"))
        {
            logger.info("Valid Input: " + fieldText);

        }
        else
        {
            logger.info("InValid Input: " + fieldText + "not allowed");
        }

        element.clear();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working now, the problem is I was not capturing the sendKeys value. I should have used getAttribute

```
f.get("https://mail.yahoo.com");
        f.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("jj%jo.com");


        //The getAttribute method returns the value of an attribute of an HTML Tag; 
        //for example if I have an input like this:
        WebElement element = f.findElement(By.id("login-username"));
        String text = element.getAttribute("value");
        System.out.println(text);

if((text).contains("@")){
    System.out.println("pass");
}
else{
    System.out.println("not pass");
}


    enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Personal_loan {

public String verified_number(String inputNumber)  // pass the parameter
{
    String validation;

    String regexNum = "[0-9]+";           //"[A-Za-z]";//"^[A-Z+$]";

    if (inputNumber.matches("[" + regexNum + "]+"))
    {
        System.out.println("valid"); 
        validation="valid";
    }
    else{

        System.out.println("Invalid character in Name field");
        validation="invalid";
    }
    return validation;

}

public String verified_str(String inputStr)
{
    String regexString = "[A-Za-z]";//"^[A-Z+$]";

    if (inputStr.matches("[" + regexString + "]+"))
    {
        System.out.println("valid"); 
    }
    else{

        System.out.println("Invalid character in Name field");
    }
    return null;

}



public static void main(String[] args) {


    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.iservefinancial.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//DIV[@itemprop='name'])[1]")).click();
    WebElement LoanAmount =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//INPUT[@id='amount_qa']"));
    WebElement Income =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//INPUT[@id='income_qa']"));
    LoanAmount.sendKeys("12345");
    Income.sendKeys("amount");

    Personal_loan pl=new Personal_loan(); //creating object


    String g =  LoanAmount.getAttribute("value");  // store the value in string
    String incomevalue = Income.getAttribute("value");


    String lavalid=pl.verified_number(g);
    String  income_valid = pl.verified_number(incomevalue);


    System.out.println("Loan Amount "+lavalid);
    System.out.println("income Amount "+income_valid);





}
```

}

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)